# Custom TextField layer / background / adapt using swift

Tags: swift, background, textfield

I would like to know if it's possible to create a custom background for a textfield using swift, for example expecting 4 letters, the textfield has 4 square. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
// Background
txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
// Placeholder
txtField.placeholder = "1"
// Corner radius
txtField.layer.cornerRadius = 8
// A Boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds
txtField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a method that will randomize a number and then create textfields according to the number that has been generated. You don´t need the random functionality of course if you already have a number. The only thing you have to do is change for `var i = 0; i < rand; i++` rand to your variable. The `textFieldEditingChanged` function is the event when the users tries to add a new character to the `textField` and there is a check to only allow one character in each `textField`.

```
let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 2)
for var i = 0; i < rand; i++ {
    let myField: UITextField = UITextField (frame:CGRectMake(CGFloat(i * 30), 50, 25, 25));
    myField.text = String(i)
    myField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    myField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldEditingChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(myField)
}
```

If you only have a `String` and you want to populate each char in a `textField`, you could do like this:

```
let word = "Car"
for var i = 0; i < word.characters.count; i++ {
    let myField: UITextField = UITextField (frame:CGRectMake(CGFloat(i * 30), 50, 25, 25));
    myField.text = String(word[word.startIndex.advancedBy(i)])
    myField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    myField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldEditingChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(myField)
}
```

**Click event for the textField**

```
func textFieldEditingChanged(target: UITextField){
     if (target.text?.characters.count > 1){
         target.text = target.text?.substringToIndex(target.text!.endIndex.predecessor())
     }
 }
```

**UPDATE**
To change responder

Declare a variable `var tagNumber = 0` and when you loop through in your for statement and create your textFields just add this row to `myField.tag = i`. In your `textFieldEditingChanged` function, add this code block:

```
if (target.tag < tagNumber){
       let nextTag: NSInteger = target.tag + 1;
       // Try to find next responder
       if let nextResponder: UIResponder! = 
       target.superview!.viewWithTag(nextTag){
           nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
       }
   }
```

Comment: no, for example if i expect "car" i want the textfield to become 3 square and when the user write down "car" the letters go in each square

Comment: @AndrewBr, check the update. I have added two examples one if you only have a number and want to generate textboxes according to that and another if you have a word.

Comment: any idea on how can i change the textfield current section with a button?

Comment: What do you mean? @AndrewBr

Comment: For example: i type A in the first textfield section then the next section become the first responder

Comment: @AndrewBr I have added an example for the first responder, if you find the post useful consider accepting the answer so that others can get help from it.

Comment: yes thank you very much! And it's done! Have a nice day!! :)